# Non-resolvable parent POM Error while Performing Maven install

Tags: maven, pom.xml, http-proxy, parent-pom

I am using maven 3.3 version and I am passing my HTTP proxy in `settings.xml` as shown below but while running maven install it is failing badly. Please help me resolve the error.

Proxy configuration:

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <id>optional</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <username>test</username>
    <password>pwd</password>
    <host>http://xxx.test1234.com</host>
    <port>1234</port>
  </proxy>
```

Log:

```
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.signalfx.public:appd-integration:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:7 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 10 The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   The project com.signalfx.public:appd-integration:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT (/app/appd-integration/appd-integration/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.signalfx.public:appd-integration:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:7 in  was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6
```

Comment: `org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:7` looks like a mistake. wouldn't that be `oss-parent-pom`?

Comment: Yeah fejese got it ,thanks!

Comment: But after running with oss-parent:pom i am recieving this issue only : Failure to find org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent-pom:pom:7 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local

Answer (score 0):

In Maven you identify artefacts with [GAVs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html) that look the following:

```
groupId:artifactId:version[:classifier]
```

From what you try to achieve I guess `7` is the version of the parent POM, so there should be no 3 fields before.

Going to the Maven central, you can browse the repository as any other Maven repository such as:

```
http://repo/path/groupIdP1/groupIdP2/artifactId/version
```

Where the artefact you're looking for is `groupIdP1.groupIdP2:artifactId:...`

SO if you go to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/ you'll find that the you actually got the artefact name right, it's `oss-parent`: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent

Going into the version directory (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7) you can see the POM you're looking for.

So the correct coordinates of the product is:

```
org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:7
```

The problem was the extra `:pom` in your original question.

---

Note that you should update your question by removing the proxy config and adding the dependency definition as this issue has nothing to do with the proxy.